# WebApi - The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to accept `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data on my webApi endpoint.  When I send a request with PostMan that has this Content-Type header explicitly set, I get an error:

> The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header

My Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/sms")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage Subscribe([FromBody]string Body) { // ideally would have access to both properties, but starting with one for now
        try {
            var messages = _messageService.SendMessage("flatout2050@gmail.com", Body);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, messages);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

The POSTMAN cap:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the request message, you can see that `Content-Type` header is being sent like this.

`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

So, you are adding the `Content-Type` header manually and POSTMAN is adding that as well, since you have selected the x-www-form-urlencoded tab.

If you remove the header you have added, it should work. I mean you will not get an error but then binding will not work because of the simple type parameter `[FromBody]string Body`. You will need to have the action method like this.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Subscribe(MyClass param) { // Access param.Body here }
public class MyClass
{
   public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Instead, if you insist on binding to `string Body`, do not choose the x-www-form-urlencoded tab. Instead choose the raw tab and send the body of `=Test`. Of course, in this case, you have to manually add the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' header. Then, the value in the body (Test) will be correctly bound to the parameter.

[image]

Comment: You're like the batman of WebAPI Badri.  Thanks for saving my day again.